# Java Libgdx properly omit class references for gwt build

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I am working on a game in java using libgdx which I am deploying to a web server I have, as well as to the google play market.

Using libgdx to handle deployment it is setup like all libgdx projects:

game           - main game code

game-android   - for android build

game-html      - for gwt build

The game allows users to save and load projects, as well as take screen shots.  Since html5 doesn't have access to any actual filesystem I cannot use those features in the same way when building the game-html version.

I have created a class called FileManager, which is instantiated in the main game code class.  It handles all of the file system related stuff.

When I go to build for game-html I have to go through the 4 or 5 other classes that reference the FileManager class and comment those lines out.  I do this in order to prevent the gwt build from throwing an error.

What is the correct way to handle building for GWT when one of your game code classes uses Gdx.files.local ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can't you just pass an argument into your Game code that determines whether it's a GWT run or not? Then just avoid the FileManager stuff if the parameter indicates it's GWT. This is similar to how you might change which input you're using depending on whether you're on desktop or Android.

Comment: I tried something like that but it seemed to be ignored during the build.  I did this:

when I load the game code I pass in a string with the device name.

So if it's android the string is "android", also can be "desktop" or "gwt"

Then I try this in the game code's create() method:


if(!device.equals("gwt")){
 this.files = new FileManager(this);
}

Comment: If you've tried something, can you post some example code along with the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Here is exactly how I tried it and the error I get from the GWT build.

I declare a string that can be "desktop", "android", or "gwt".

I check that string before instantiating the FileManager class (which contains the FileHandle object that gwt ends up breaking over).

I check it like this:

`
if(!device.equals("gwt")){
 this.files = new FileManager(this);
}
`

Then I get this error:GWT Compilation Failed.

When I scroll up through the output log I eventually find the culprit:

`
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/***//SuperContraption/supercontraption/src/supercontraption/FileManager.java'

`

Comment: And that is the line in FileManager that the FileHandle object is created.  So it seems like checking that string before creating the FileManager object doesn't stop it from breaking the gwt build.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is during compile-time, so the if statement won't help. Instead of including your FileManager logic in the main Game project, you'll probably have to pull it out and put it in the Android project. Maybe pass some kind of a callback (like a listener) from the Android project to the main project, that way the GWT project never has to worry about it?

Comment: I think you are right although I'd prefer all the feature related code remain in the core game project.  I'll post whatever I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a runtime issue if you can and use `if(Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.WebGL) {}` or `isLocalStorageAvailable()`.

It seems like support for local storage was planned - "Preferences and local files, most likely implemented via the Web Storage APIs." http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2308 but I guess it just hasn't been implemented yet.

You could always write some [platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) that uses [GWT to access HTML5 local storage](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html) or even work on updating the [backend](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtFiles.java) yourself.

Comment: The specific issue is with this function:



 `public Array<String> getList(String dir) {
  Array<String> files = new Array<String>();
  FileHandle dirHandle;
  if(Gdx.files.isLocalStorageAvailable()){
   dirHandle = Gdx.files.local(base+"/"+dir);
   for (FileHandle entry : dirHandle.list()) {
    if(!(Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.WebGL)){
     String fileName = entry.file().getName();
     files.add(fileName);
    }
   }
  }
  return files;
 }`



Even with both checks the build still breaks.  However if I comment out the line with `entry.file().getName()` , then it builds.

Comment: What is the actual error? Not the line that just says error, there (hopefully) should be a cause listed. 

Read the platform specific code webpage again. If you make an interface for your FileManager and then only put the current FileManager in your desktop/android projects you should be okay. You'll just have to make a FileManager without the problem code for your web project.